# JHIpster KeyCloak OAuth, Proxy error during Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak

I configured a JHipster Project with Keycloak, but during the Login I always get an Error.

The Message after the Login Button looks like the following:

***Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:9000/oauth2/authorization/oidc***

I am using Windows 10, my windows/system32/driver/etc/host File looks like this:

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 keycloak

Do I need to set smth else in my Hostfile ?

Thanks

Comment: I run a docker container like (https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-oauth-example/blob/master/src/main/docker/keycloak.yml)

Comment: You mean the one generated by JHipster, not the one from your link, right? You added keycloak to your hosts file, so did you also change the application.yml accordingly?

Comment: Does it work if you run everything on port 8080?

Comment: i solved the problem, a port was not exposed and I had to reinstall Docker